# Ionic/Angular Android app crash with Barcode Scanner

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've started writing a basic app so I can scan barcodes and email them out to people. It's using latest version of Ionic and the barcode scanner ([GitHub](https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner)).

Scanning works and I can display the list of scanned results. I'm currently using HTML local storage via a service/factory but I ran into this same issue using ngCordova/sqlite. If I scan a new barcode and then open the modal so as to change an attribute (which works) upon closing the modal the app crashes after a few moments. The change does get written to storage, as upon re-opening what I changed is present.

It appears to only crash when I do this for the first time for each object. If I start the application back up and change it to something else I don't get a crash. I can't for the life of me figure out what's causing the crash (I've re-written it in case I messed up along the way) and the I can't find anything in the logcat results (wasn't sure what to post).

What's worse, if I remove the scanning function and just enter something directly into storage so I can test in a web browser, things don't crash in a web browser or on Android. It appears something between the Barcode Scanner and the modal or local storage doesn't get along. I've tried this using routes and same result.

Relevant code samples are at http://git.io/vm4W7

P.S. I don't have iOS developer account or device so couldn't test if it Android or iOS specific.

EDIT: Using `adb logcat | grep -i "console"` with my device plugged into the only errors I get are below

```
I/chromium(29216): [INFO:CONSOLE(173)] "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-console/www/console-via-logger.js (173)
D/PluginManager(29216): exec() call to unknown plugin: Console
I/chromium(29216): [INFO:CONSOLE(173)] "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-console/www/console-via-logger.js (173)
D/PluginManager(29216): exec() call to unknown plugin: Console
```

EDIT 2: [GapDebug](https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/) shows same messages on crash, with nothing more informative.

Comment: Try testing it in the android emulator with logging enabled http://wildermuth.com/2013/4/30/Debugging_PhoneGap_with_the_Android_Console

Comment: It doesn't crash in the emulators unfortunately because I have to remove the reliance on $cordovaBarcodeScanner and just imitate the insertion of a scan result. I am going to try and narrow down the logcat results running off my android device though as in that post.

Comment: You should use this [one](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner). Simply use `cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner`

Comment: Tried it too with previous version to no luck. Still getting a logless crash for no reason I can find.

Comment: Appears I spoke too soon. I tried that plugin when using sqlite still and it caused crashes. I've tried it just using localStorage and things seem to have been stabilized, weird.